# How to convert anonymous list to string.?

Tags: c#

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
var IDList = from listings in doc.Root.Elements("SearchData")
             select (string)listings.Attribute("ListingID");
string list = string.Join(",",IDList);
```

In above case I trying to convert `var IDList` to string list separated by comma but it error as `string.Join(",",IDList)` has some invalid argument.

How to do that conversion?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: `string list = string.Join(",",IDList);` this line gives error as `string.Join(",",IDList);` has some invalid arguments..

Comment: again: what's the exact error message?

Comment: You are not on .NET 3.5, are you?

Comment: Works on my machine.

Comment: If it doesn't think that is correct what type does it think IDList is?

Comment: @Kailas could you please post the error message that the compiler or the runtime gives you?

Comment: The only possibility I see is that, in spite of what you are saying, you are using version 3.5 of the .NET framework, which does no provide an overloaded version of "string.Join" that takes an IEnumerable<String> argument.

Comment: go to your project settings and set target framework to .Net 4.5 framework. having visual studio 2015 does not mean you are using .Net 4.5. (you didnt said that but i guessed it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Join` takes an array, you pass an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Fix it like this:

```
  string list = string.Join(",",IDList.ToArray());
```

Comment: it does take `IEnumerable<string>` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes I saw, it should work - but I can't see what would be wrong apart from the .net version

Comment: Clearly there is some lacking in detail

Comment: @Kailas you're welcome, but you are not on .net 4.5 if that worked